# How can I do a query using Django but with more filters and update?

Tags: python, django

I know that to do a query using Django I have to do this:

`MyModel.objects.filter(pk=some_value).update(field1='some value')`

But if I have more values about the filter and the update does this work?

`MyModel.objects.filter(pk=some_value, pk1=some_value1).update(field1='some value', field2='some value2')`

Comment: Yes; the documentation of [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) and [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) is pretty clear on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use filters and update in more than one field as you have stated.

**Extra:** If you want to compare a single field with many values, what you can do is put the values in a list as:

```
values_list = [some_value1, some_value2, ...]
```

Then you can filter by checking if the field matches any value in the list as:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=values_list).update(field1='some value', ...)
```